# python game CLI

Tags: python

I was trying to make 20 x 2 is a game played by a human player with a computer. It’s a simple board game which requires some dice to play. I have tried human and computer but want to do this, so not sure what code I am doing wrong. any help highly appreciated

```py
import random
import datetime

# initialize the game board
board = [['-' for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(2)]
board[0][0] = 'X'  # human player
board[1][0] = 'X'  # computer

# initialize variables
turn = 1  # human player goes first
human_pos = 0
computer_pos = 0
human_moves = 0
computer_moves = 0
human_hits = 0
computer_hits = 0

# function to print the game board
def print_board():
    print('+----' * 20 + '+')
    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(20):
            print('|', board[row][col], ' ', end='')
        print('|')
        print('+----' * 20 + '+')

# function to roll the dice
def roll_dice():
    return random.randint(1, 6)

# function to move the player's pawn
def move_pawn(player, steps):
    global human_pos, computer_pos
    if player == 'human':
        pos = human_pos
        row = 0
    else:
        pos = computer_pos
        row = 1
    board[row][pos] = '-'
    pos += int(steps/2)
    if pos >= 20:
        pos = 20
    if player == 'human':
        human_pos = pos
    else:
        computer_pos = pos
    if board[row][pos] == 'X':
        pos = 0
        board[row][pos] = 'X'
        if player == 'human':
            human_hits += 1
        else:
            computer_hits += 1
    else:
        board[row][pos] = 'X'

# function to check if a player has won
def check_win(player):
    if player == 'human':
        pos = human_pos
    else:
        pos = computer_pos
    if pos >= 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# main game loop
while True:
    print_board()
    if turn == 1:
        input('Press Enter to roll the dice')
        dice = roll_dice()
        print('You rolled a', dice)
        if dice == 6:
            move_pawn('human', dice)
            print_board()
            input('Press Enter to start the game')
            turn = 2
        else:
            print('You need to roll a 6 to start the game')
    else:
        dice = roll_dice()
        print('Computer rolled a', dice)
        if dice == 6:
            move_pawn('computer', dice)
            print_board()
            input('Press Enter to start the game')
            turn = 1
        else:
            move_pawn('computer', dice)
            print_board()
            if check_win('computer'):
                print('Computer wins!')
                break
            turn = 1
            input('Press Enter to continue')

    if check_win('human'):
        print('You win!')
        break

# count the number of moves and hits for each player
human_moves = human_pos + human_hits
computer_moves = computer_pos + computer_hits

# save the game session to a text file
date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M')
filename = date_time + '.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Human\n')
    f.write('Total moves: ' + str(human_moves) + '\n')
    f.write
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\abiruk\Downloads\main.py", line 77, in <module>
    move_pawn('human', dice)
  File "c:\Users\abiruk\Downloads\main.py", line 48, in move_pawn
    if board[row][pos] == 'X':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried human and computer but want to do this, so not sure what code I am doing wrong. any help highly appreciated

Comment: Looks like you are getting a list index out of range error.  I'd refactor this, and really try to split some of the concepts into classes or more functions.  If you divide the problem up small enough, it is usually easier to see where the issue is.

Comment: Either `computer_pos` or `human_pos` is going above 19. You'll need to step through your code to see why this is happening.

Comment: `pos += int(steps/2)` doesn't seem to do anything to prevent it from getting too high.

Comment: If you increase a value that is used as an index, you should use the `%` operator (remainder after division) to make sure it stays inside the upper bound of the list length (hint: look at `pos`)

Comment: If you are a beginner I also suggest using Python3.11 as it has better error messages

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're taking `board[row][20]`, while `board[row]` only contains 0 - 19. This is because the first element of a list is accessed as `my_list[0]`, the second as `my_list[1]`, and thus the 20th as `my_list[19]`

There are some other things, so from the start:

- I would define `board` as `[['-']*20]*2`, since it's smaller and easier to read than `[['-' for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(2)]`. The problem is, that they're referencing to the same `'-'`. We still have to add one to solve the `IndexError` though:

```py
board = [['-' for _ in range(21)] for _ in range(2)]
```

- In the `move_pawn()` function, you have to set globals for everything you edit. As you forgot some, here:

```py
global board, human_pos, computer_pos, human_hits, computer_hits
```

- In the `move_pawn()` function, `if board[row][pos] == 'X':` will never run, because when the pawn is moved forward, `X` will not be there. Instead, you have to check the other row. Also, the `pos = 0` there is unnecessary, so I removed it.

```py
if board[1 if row == 0 else 0][pos] == 'X':
```

Here's the entire code (with a bit of my formatting too):

```py
import random
import datetime

# initialize the game board
board = [['-' for _ in range(21)] for _ in range(2)]
board[0][0] = 'X'  # human player
board[1][0] = 'X'  # computer

# initialize variables
turn = 1  # human player goes first

human_pos = 0
computer_pos = 0

human_moves = 0
computer_moves = 0

human_hits = 0
computer_hits = 0


def print_board() -> None:
    """function to print the game board"""
    print('+----' * 20 + '+')
    for row in range(2):
        for col in range(20):
            print('|', board[row][col], ' ', end='')
        print('|')
        print('+----' * 20 + '+')

    return None


def roll_dice() -> int:
    """function to roll the dice"""
    return random.randint(1, 6)


def move_pawn(player: str, steps: int) -> None:
    """function to move the player's pawn"""
    global board, human_pos, computer_pos, human_hits, computer_hits

    # Get the position
    if player == 'human':
        pos = human_pos
        row = 0
    else:
        pos = computer_pos
        row = 1
    board[row][pos] = '-'
    pos += int(steps/2)

    # Set pos to 20 if it's above
    if pos >= 20:
        pos = 20

    # Set the global pos
    if player == 'human':
        human_pos = pos
    else:
        computer_pos = pos

    # Check for the position on the other row:
    if board[1 if row == 0 else 0][pos] == 'X':
        board[row][pos] = 'X'

        if player == 'human':
            human_hits += 1
        else:
            computer_hits += 1
    else:
        board[row][pos] = 'X'

    return None


def check_win(player: str) -> bool:
    """function to check if a player has won"""
    if player == 'human':
        pos = human_pos
    else:
        pos = computer_pos
    if pos >= 20:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# main game loop
while True:
    print_board()
    if turn == 1:
        input('Press Enter to roll the dice')
        dice = roll_dice()
        print('You rolled a', dice)
        if dice == 6:
            move_pawn('human', dice)
            print_board()
            input('Press Enter to start the game')
            turn = 2
        else:
            print('You need to roll a 6 to start the game')
    else:
        dice = roll_dice()
        print('Computer rolled a', dice)
        if dice == 6:
            move_pawn('computer', dice)
            print_board()
            input('Press Enter to start the game')
            turn = 1
        else:
            move_pawn('computer', dice)
            print_board()
            if check_win('computer'):
                print('Computer wins!')
                break
            turn = 1
            input('Press Enter to continue')

    if check_win('human'):
        print('You win!')
        break

# count the number of moves and hits for each player
human_moves = human_pos + human_hits
computer_moves = computer_pos + computer_hits

# save the game session to a text file
date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M')
filename = date_time + '.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Human\n')
    f.write('Total moves: ' + str(human_moves) + '\n')
```

Comment: 4 'x' are going to show up

Comment: I changed `[['-']*20]*2` back to `board = [['-' for _ in range(21)] for _ in range(2)]`, this should resolve the issue. Please accept my answer if it helped.